Rank of rational matrix modulo prime
I have a rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{m \times n}$ ($m < n$) with rational entries and I want to verify that $\text{rank}(A) = m-1$.
I already know that $\text{rank}(A) \geq m-1$. So, I guess, in fact, I want to verify that $A$ does not have full rank.
However, using SageMath, computing the rank of this matrix directly over the rationals is too slow for my application. Therefore, my idea would be to compute $\text{rank}(A_p)$, where $A_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{m \times n}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by taking all entries modulo a prime $p$. Working over finite fields is a lot faster and computing this rank over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ would be fast enough. So, my question is: can I give a bound on $p$ that ensures $\text{rank}(A_p) = \text{rank}(A)$?
Or are there any other methods to verify $\text{rank}(A) = m-1$ in a more efficient way than directly computing the rank of $A$?
Thanks a lot for any help!
